# Why can't I access the array with index directly?

Tags: php

I got confused when I was trying to access an array element directly with its index. I guess I could explain it better in coding:-

I am having an object of Employee Class and I TypeCast it to array and tried to display it like this:

```
$arrOfObj = (array) $objEmployee;

$arrKeys = array_keys( $arrOfObj );

display( $arrOfObj ); // display() is a method in my library that prints an array in a mannered way.
```

this gives me the following output :-

```
Array
(
   [*m_UserId] => 1155
   [*m_EmailPassword] => 
   [*m_IsAssignedToManagementCompany] => 
   [*m_ManagementCompanyId] => 
   [*m_DepartmentId] => 3
   [*m_DesignationId] => 4
   [*m_EmployeeCompletedMonth] => 
   [*m_EmployeeCompletedDay] => 
   [*m_EmailAddress] =>showket.mca@gmail.com
   ------
   ------
 )
```

Now here I dont understand this Star(*). when my member variables are simple like m_UserId, m_EmialPassword and So on where from it gets this Star. and when I try to display the same with following 2 statements I got an error :-

```
display( $arrOfObj['*m_EmailAddress'] );
```

**or**

```
display( $arrOfObj['m_EmailAddress'] );
```

Both give the Error message **Undefined index: m_EmailAddress**

And when i try to do it this way It works fine :-

```
display( $arrOfObj[$arrKeys[8]] );
```

The last one works fine, Can anyone explain me the problem.

```
            display( $arrOfObj[$arrKeys[11]] );
            display( $arrOfObj['m_strEmailAddress'] );
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; **protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.**
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Try `var_dump(bin2hex($arrKeys[8]))` for enlightenment. Also see the example in the above linked manual.

Comment: Then how can i access the array protected keys with star, and u have not replied to the last 3 lines of my question.

Comment: If you get the "real" key value from the extracted keys, you obviously get the correct key. To form a correct key yourself, you have to include the NUL bytes, like so: `"\0*\0m_strEmailAddress"`.

Comment: It's `"\0*\0strThree"`. Double quoted strings and the NUL bytes are around the asterisk.

Comment: Hey @deceze - So in order to access a protected variable, you have to use the return of var_dump(bin2hex($arrKeys[8])) as a key? Is that right?

Comment: @Jay No, it means that you should probably read the class's documentation to learn which method you need to call to get the data you want. Having a protected property with absolutely no way to access it is pretty pointless, I doubt anyone would design a class like this on purpose. If you're supposed to get the data, the class will provide a way for you to do so. You just need to read its documentation and/or source code.

Comment: @deceze Great, just figured it out via the documentation Thanks for your help.