# How to access *key value in array using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have below array with key combined * i want get the value using array key

i got response from api

```
Array   (
[pos] => Bitpay\Token Object
    (
        [token:protected] => 8Q13oFMiBLBcqFCK5wWfhUYxxhcpkq4C6Xqh6ipgbxTm
        [resource:protected] => 
        [facade:protected] => pos
        [createdAt:protected] => 
        [policies:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [pairingCode:protected] => 
        [pairingExpiration:protected] => 
    )

[pos/invoice] => Bitpay\Token Object
    (
        [token:protected] => 4XyeM78xv6ywzTB3Cc2yak7Bb9duAW1DaCu5XDAVuSEQ
        [resource:protected] => 
        [facade:protected] => pos/invoice
        [createdAt:protected] => 
        [policies:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [pairingCode:protected] => 
        [pairingExpiration:protected] => 
    )
```

)

after i convert array i got below array structure, I want get a token:protected value, How can i get this

```
Array(
[*token] => 8Q13oFMiBLBcqFCK5wWfhUYxxhcpkq4C6Xqh6ipgbxTm
[*resource] => 
[*facade] => pos
[*createdAt] => 
[*policies] => Array
    (
    )

[*pairingCode] => 
[*pairingExpiration] =>
```

)

I want take get a token value, Any one Please help.

Comment: `$myArray['*token']`?

Comment: What you have tried for it??

Comment: you really really really need to do a search.. thats about the simplest question I think ive ever seen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I access the array with index directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514558/why-cant-i-access-the-array-with-index-directly)

Comment: i take take using key * because special charater found in key

Comment: @arkascha that is not work, i have tried

Comment: If you meant "`$myArray['*token']` does not work" in your last comment, then you should elaborate on that. You must have missed something, since that _definitely_ works. So the _real_ question here is: what is different in your situation from what you asked here?

Comment: @arkascha this array comes from API, How can i elaborate this

Comment: You can explain _how_ you tested my suggestion to demonstrate how you came to the conclusion that it does not work. Add a simple example script to your question.

Comment: Is your API really returning an array, or a dump of an array as a string?

Comment: its returning obj just i contere obj to array formate

Comment: If it's an object, you should be able to access it with something like `$myObj->{'*token'}`. If that's not the problem, then I think you need to post more code; both the code that receives the api call, and what the api is sending back to you. There's too much guess work for anyone to help you otherwise.

Comment: i have edited more detaily please any one help me

Comment: Something is still missing here, I think. If you really have the array structure described above, then the answer I supplied below should work.

Comment: I given full response here just i converted object to array.

Answer (score 0):

Using quotes should make it all possible:

```
<?php

$myArray = array(
    '*token' => '8Q13oFMiBLBcqFCK5wWfhUYxxhcpkq4C6Xqh6ipgbxTm',
    '*resource' => '',
    '*facade' => 'pos',
    '*createdAt' => '',
    '*policies' => array
           (
           ),

    '*pairingCode' => '',
    '*pairingExpiration' => '',

);
print $myArray['*token'];
?>
```